# Birthday Date Auto generate year for 18 years old

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

My question is how to automatically set the date range for 18 years old, like for example today is 2015, so the date range must be 1935-1997, don't mind the 1935. Because the date range is for 18 years old and above, so when it come to 2016 the date range will automatically set to 1935-1998 then so on so forth as the year comes by.

Here's the current code with javascript on it

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#from2" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:1997',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to2" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to2" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
   changeYear: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      yearRange: '1935:1997' ,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from2" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<label for="birthday">Birthday</label>
<input type="text" id="from2" name="from">

 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Well as you can see you in my javascript function the range function is hardcoded. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the range:

```
var startDate = "1935";
var endDate = new Date().getFullYear() - 18;    
var interval = startDate + ":" + endDate;
```

Set the range to the DatePicker:

```
yearRange: interval
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6Ljyk00w/5/)

Comment: Thanks! but can you please try insert that code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Vista/6Ljyk00w/) because I tried and doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I edited my answer with a link to a fiddle (yours updated).

Comment: can you suggest me that how can i also restrict on month also